# How do you block someone who has subscribed to you?

Tags: facebook

How do you unsubscribe someone that has subscribed to you? My son has a woman who has subscribed to him on Facebook and is sending him links to objectionable sites. How does he stop this?

Answer (score 8):

You can block that person from your profile. He/She will not be able to contact you in anyway after that.

Click the `Report/Block` option from the drop down which appears on the top right side of that person's profile.

[image]

You can disable the `Subscribers` feature altogether to avoid such inconvenience in the future. Follow the steps as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to go to the person's profile and block them. If they have Timeline enabled, click on the cog-wheel on the right and select `Report/Block`. If they still have the old profile style, it'll be in the left-most column under their list of friends.

In addition, your son should go to his [Subscription management page](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?sk=subscribers&filter=0) and change the settings so that either only friends or friends of friends could comment on his public updates.

Moreover, he should not post public updates if he's concerned with strangers posting inappropriate comments. This is accomplished at the time of publishing just one update by changing privacy to Friends (Facebook remembers the last privacy setting for posts).